# I am trying to calculate the point of intersection between a line and plane in 3D

Tags: geometry

My plane is currently defined by three points (P1, P2, P3). I used the cross product method to define the plane in c++. I have a line intersecting this plane and I need to find the point of intersection the line and plane. How would I carry this out.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection

This is a link to give on an idea of what am doing. I currently trying to program this in C++.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47594/plane-intersecting-line-segment and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83990/line-and-plane-intersection-in-3d. Also see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-PlaneIntersection.html.

Comment: Hey David I had a question in the link you sent me, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-PlaneIntersection.html , I have to divide the two 4 by 4 matrices in order to get t. what is the first row  of the matrix (1 , 1 , 1 , 1) and (1 , 1 , 1 , 0).

Comment: Actually you need to divide the _determinant_ of one matrix by the _determinant_ of the other. Very convenient for mathematicians and users of MATLAB, not necessarily so convenient for C++ programmers. You either need to find a good linear algebra library or write your own determinant function. I don't know any particularly intuitive visualization for why there is an extra row of 1s (and a 0) in the matrices, but I do know that if you accurately compute the determinant using those values, you'll be performing the desired computation.